# addAttr not working in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a sample code :

```
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" value="" />
```

And jquery

```
$('#color').change(function(){
    $('#color').addAttr('value', 'test');
});
```

When I change value in textbox is result `value=""` and error in firebug `$("#color").addAttr is not a function`

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 57):

It's called `.attr()`, not `.addAttr()`.

You should also replace your inner `$('#color')` with `$(this)` to indicate that you're manipulating the same input that's being changed:

```
$('#color').change(function(){
    $(this).attr('value', 'test');
});
```

Answer (score 18):

You are confused about `removeAttr()` and you think that `addAttr()` exists, **that's wrong.**

The function you want is `.attr()` - nowadays `.prop()`, I believe.

Comment: Something else that might lead to that confusion is that `addClass` exists, and it would be nice to be able to add attributes like `required` and `disabled` that don't have values in a more semantic way

Answer (score 5):

You could also do:

```
$('#color').change(function(){
    $(this).val('test');
});
```