# How to remove the disabled attribute of a href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I use this line

> $("#edit-link-1").removeAttr("href");

It disables the link.

Now I want to enable the same link again. So I tried this line, but its kind of not working :(

> $("#edit-link-1").addAttr("href",true);

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> 
</script>

<a href="#" id="edit-link-1">Link1</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#edit-link-1").removeAttr("href");
    $("#edit-link-1").addAttr("href",true);
</script>
```

Comment: `href="true"` is what you are trying to add.  I'm assuming that is not correct.

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070864/disable-a-links-using-attr-disabled

Comment: Having an `<a>` without href may cause problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addAttr not working in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407622/addattr-not-working-in-jquery)

Comment: "kind of not working" - very help technical diagnostic there...  maybe look in your console and see `$(...).addAttr is not a function` then enter SO search "addAttr" and read first result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery the correct way of adding an attribute is:

```
$("#edit-link-1").attr("href", 'https://www.google.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you have another option, depends on wich jQuery version are you working on.

Since v1.6 you can use `prop`, http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
var $link = $("#edit-link-1");
$link.prop('href', 'https://www.google.com/');
```

Regards